# how to select all listview items?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to select all listview items ?

Comment: There are many technologies and many types of listview in the C# world: asp.net, winforms, silverlight, wpf.  Some more information and/or some code would help.

Comment: Since most of the answers are for winforms, it probably wouldn't hurt anything to just add that tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If there aren't very many items, this will do it:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in myListView.Items)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

If there are a *lot* of items, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146677/43846) for how to use [`LVM_SETITEMSTATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setitemstate).

Comment: What if you have thousands of items? Is there a way of making this approach faster?

Comment: Calling [LVM_SETITEMSTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setitemstate) passing -1 as the index is the low-level way to set all items.

Comment: @stuartd it would be helpful to post your own answer with C# code to do this rather then posting a vague comment.

Comment: @stuartd I have no mean intent. I'm saying that your comment could be a good answer and should stand on it's own. The link you provided has some information about C++ so it would be helpful to give an example of how you would use this in C# code.

Comment: OK, sorry. I didn't add it to the question because I've never actually had to use it. There's a C# example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146677/43846 though

Answer (score 9):

Just pass your listview and checkstate to the function.

```
public void CheckAllItems(ListView lvw, bool check)
{
    lvw.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().ToList().ForEach(item => item.Checked = check);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the listview is in virtual mode. How can i achieve this using Virtual Mode?

Comment: Wie have our own Each-Extension, but I prefere your Linq solution. It is well readable.

Answer (score 2):

for UWP c# this is how I did it.

I have a Listview called, *MembersLis*t. to select all members I used the built-in method SellectAll() from the listview class.

The following code worked for me:

MembersList.SellectAll();

Comment: yes you can select all items in the listview with this code
in my case i use imagelistview
 
imageListView1.SelectAll();

Answer (score 2):

There is already an accepted answer for this but I use something similar to this:

```
lv.BeginUpdate();
List<ListViewItem> items = (from i in lv.Items).ToList;
items.ForEach(i => i.Selected == true);
lv.EndUpdate();
```

It seems to run much faster if there's several thousand items. Also, since we're using `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()`, the ListView control doesn't update after selecting each item.